# What npm package can I install to archive exactly going to the next step in React.js

Tags: reactjs, npm, package

I am looking for an npm package in react that I can install to archive something exactly like what am having in the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their are a lot of possibilities:

Component libraries:

https://mantine.dev/core/stepper/

https://mui.com/material-ui/react-stepper/

NPM Packages:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-form-stepper

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-stepper-horizontal

Just search for a React Stepper and you will be amazed by the results.

Comment: Am having issues using either of mantine or material UI, can you please help . An error is being throw after the installation . The error is from the stepper

Comment: Could you please provide more information?